# Getting out of multiple for loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a homework exercise that asks for a script that finds smallest 3-digit Armstrong Number.

I wrote my script. It works fine for finding these numbers, but I don’t know how to stop at first Armstrong number.

Here is my code

```
a=0;
b=0;
c=0;
for x1=1:1:9
    a=x1^3;
    for x2=0:1:9
        b=x2^3;
        for x3=0:1:9
            c=x3^3;
            d=(x1*100 + x2*10 + x3);
            if (a+b+c) == (d)
                disp(d)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It normally prints `153 370 371 407`.
If I use `break` after `disp` it just gets out of first for and not all, and prints `153 370 407`.

Comment: If you want to break after a specific number, then use an if statement to test for d, then call break.

Comment: Although MATLAB does not require a proper indentation of the code, it is widely appreciated ;) Tip: use **ctrl + i** to indent everything automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop loops with the keyword [`break`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html). However, this just stops one loop. You have now to options

1. set some kind of flag and check it in every loop to terminate (`break`) it (*aka: the proper way*)
2. use [`return`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html) (*aka: the nasty way*)

Option 1

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
FLAG_STOP = false;
for x1 = 1:9
    a = x1^3;
    for x2 = 0:9
        b = x2^3;
        for x3 = 0:9
            c = x3^3;
            d = (x1*100 + x2*10 + x3);
            if (a+b+c) == (d)
                disp(d)

                % set flag
                FLAG_STOP = true;
                break
            end
        end
        if FLAG_STOP
            break
        end
    end
    if FLAG_STOP
        break
    end
end
```

Option 2

**a word of warning**:

> (...) it does not just exit the loop; it exits the script or function and
>   returns control to the invoking program or command prompt.

i.e. all statements after `return` will be ignored -- with no matter whether they are part of a loop or not

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
for x1 = 1:9
    a = x1^3;
    for x2 = 0:9
        b = x2^3;
        for x3 = 0:9
            c = x3^3;
            d = (x1*100 + x2*10 + x3);
            if (a+b+c) == (d)
                disp(d)

                return % <<<<<<<<<<<<
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I thought about first way you mentioned but couldn't get it right thanks for it. Second way looks too powerful to use if its ends code directly like you said. I will go with flags thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `return` as recommended in @max's answer you may use [try/catch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) and [error](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html) to handle such cases:

```
try
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    for x1 = 1:9
        a = x1^3;
        for x2 = 0:9
            b = x2^3;
            for x3 = 0:9
                c = x3^3;
                d = (x1*100 + x2*10 + x3);
                if (a+b+c) == (d)
                    disp(d) 
                    error("") ;
                end
            end
        end
    end
catch
end
```